# How to make separate form radio buttons independent

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

To specify, I have a `for` loop running over each `employee` in an `employee_list`. I'm  printing a form I have in `forms.py` for each employee, which just consists of a single radio button with the choices "Absent" or "Present". However, in the webpage, if I select any option for `Employee 1`, then click on any of the options for `Employee 2`, it deselects the one I selected for `Employee 1`, as for some reason it renders it as one radio choice? I want to be able to select separate options for each employee 
 
 ***CODE*** 
 
`mark_attendance.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<form action="{% url 'confirm' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-header">
          <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee name</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for employee in employee_list %}
                    {{<tr>
                    <td>{{employee}}</td>
                    <td>
                        {{ form }}
                    </td>
                    </tr>}}
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms

class AttendanceForm(forms.Form):
    ATTENDANCE_CHOICES = [
        ('Present', 'Present'),
        ('Absent', 'Absent'),
    ]
    decision = forms.CharField(label='Attendance', widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=ATTENDANCE_CHOICES))
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Attendance
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Student
from .forms import AttendanceForm
from datetime import datetime



employee_list = ["John", "Jane", "Jacob", "Mark", "Jingleheimer", "Rob", "Schmidt"]

# Create your views here.
@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

@login_required
def attendance(request):
    now = timezone.now().date
    status = 0
    return render(request, 'attendance.html', {
        "date": now,
        "status": status,
    })

@login_required
def mark_attendance(request):
    employee_list = Student.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AttendanceForm(request.POST)
        for employee in employee_list:
            if form.is_valid():
                decision = form.cleaned_data['decision']
                status = Attendance(student=employee, date=datetime.now(), status=decision)
                status.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('mark_attendance.html')
    else:
        form = AttendanceForm()

    return render(request, 'mark_attendance.html', {
        "form": form,
        "employee_list": employee_list,
    })

# @login_required
# def confirm(request):
#     status = request.POST.get('status')
#     print(status)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate id on each radio element i think

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Django forms and I don't know if I can set a different name for each of the iterations the form is being displayed, do you know how I can do that?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).